# How can I enable/disable the Windows 8 Surface Pro's trackpad, now that the Trackpad Settings app is unavailable?

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, microsoft-surface

[Earlier this year](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfacc-surfcover/how-do-i-disable-the-surface-pro-trackpad-on-the/82537a23-7a67-422a-bfb2-0b26691db98f?msgId=6dd1e6d5-0af4-4e37-aea5-f8c875bc9ba7), anyone wishing to disable or toggle the Trackpad on the Surface's keyboard could download the [Trackpad Settings app](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/indstillinger-for-pegefelt/5a4e4cdf-4d60-4084-8d9f-61d2e8f4830b). However, it seems that this app is no longer available on the Windows Store (even though it still has a web page, apparently). My search for a replacement has been fruitless, and even the [Surface help docs](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/trackpad-a-builtin-mouse) still refer to this now-unavailable app.

**So... given this situation, how can I toggle my Surface's trackpad?**

Just to show it really appears to be gone...

#### Some search results

[image: Store search results showing the Trackpad Settings app]

#### ... and the store page for that one result.

[image: The store page for the Trackpad Settings app, saying "Sorry, this app is no longer available"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is still available.
I just uninstalled / reinstalled it to be sure.
Check again to see if it shows up for you.
In case locale matters, I'm en-US.

Comment: It's suddenly available again. I even checked last night or the night before and it wasn't available... but now it is. I wonder what happened. Thanks!